# Android: TranslateAnimation - move View on top of ActionBar

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, translate-animation

Is it possible to move a View from the center of the screen up until it is *on top* of the ActionBar?

I know how to make TranslateAnimations, but so far if I move Views up, they end up below the ActionBar.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i get you.. But if you define your animation in anim folder inside resources.. You can write: toYDelta = "-100%P" so it's going to go outside the screen !!!
I hope it's helpful

Comment: What I think @Terry is trying to do (and what I'm trying to do) is move the view to where it is still INSIDE the screen, but IN FRONT OF the action bar. When you translate a view to the same Y position as the action bar, it is hidden behind the action bar by default.